# How should I visualise a WebSocket connection to an AWS ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket

AWS [ALBs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/) support HTTP and WebSockets natively. My understanding of a HTTP request to an ALB is that the client will set up a TCP connection to the ALB and send a HTTP request, the ALB will inspect the content of the HTTP request, make a TCP connection to one of the target backends and send the request on.

Is this the same with WebSockets? Will the ALB have two long running TCP connections, one to the client and one to the target backend, with a two separate WebSocket connections (i.e. will the ALB send its own HTTP upgrade request to the target backend) or will the ALB simply relay the HTTP upgrade request from the client?

Answer (score 0):

you are right: the upgrade request will be sent to the backend.

the TCP connection will be build between the client and the backend througth the ALB/proxy/reverse proxy

Comment: Right about which? That two distinct upgrade requests will be sent (from client to ALB and from ALB to backend) or that the ALB will forward the upgrade request to the backend?

Comment: sorry for confusion: websocket will build a channel between your client and your backend, with only one websocket connection. The ALB will work like a socks proxy, transparently.